# SQL AVG() in Big Query and Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, google-bigquery

Anyone else having different values when calculating avg() in Google Big Query and compare it to Oracle SQL? Sum,min,max are similar but AVG() is always generating different output.

Comment: Round up errors?

Comment: If the other aggregates are merely 'similar' then maybe the data is just different at the point you're querying.

Comment: @ASPYOK . . . Please provide sample data, the results you are getting from the two systems, and the queries you are using.  And, quantify the difference.

Comment: Try using the `NUMERIC` type in BigQuery to ensure that you don't have precision loss with `FLOAT64`.

Comment: voting to close this question until you can provide any examples we can reproduce

Answer (score -1):

```
WHERE
  (
   MERCHANDISE_SN.TRANS_DT  BETWEEN  @prompt('Enter value for ALL MERCH - Trans Dt (Start):','D',,Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:0)  AND  @prompt('Enter value for ALL MERCH - Trans Dt (End):','D',,Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:1)
   AND
   MERCHANDISE_SN.PUR_CHAN_CD  NOT IN  ( 'T','O'  )
  )
```

need this in BQSQL- GCP

Comment: Can you provide some context? This answer doesn't address the question clearly.